# Rails unable to render ajax flash message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm seeing some strange behavior in my app.  It's a Rails 4 app that uses JQuery.  The app's use of javascript is pretty vanilla (i.e. no Angular, React, Ember stuff in the mix).

On the Account Settings page, there's a form where the user can toggle the value to auto-renew a subscription.  When they toggle, there's a AJAX call made to the subscriptions controller.

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

def update
  subscription_id = params['id']
  updated_preference = params['auto-renew']
  update = subscription.update_attributes(auto_renew: updated_preference)

  respond_to do |format|
    if update
      format.js { flash[:success] = "Auto-Renew information has been updated." }
    else
       format.js { flash[:error] = "Something went wrong. Please try again later." }
      end
  end
end
```

The desired behavior is that after the update is processed, a flash message appears at the top of the screen.  I set the flash message in the action above.  Inside the template for the update action, I scroll up to the top of the page.

```
# inside app/views/subscriptions/update.js.erb
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0)
```

I'm seeing behavior where (1) the call to subscriptions#update is successful, (2) the flash message does appear and then (3) when I click a link to go to the account settings page, THEN when the page loads, the flash message appears.  Refreshing the same page doesn't do anything, but clicking the link does.

I think part of this issue may be that the account settings are managed by a different controller than the subscriptions and Rails is having trouble figuring out what to do after it renders the template associated the subscriptions#update action.  But honestly, I'm at a loss for what could be causing this.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  Also, can anyone tell me what I should do get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash does not render in JS, so it only appears on the next HTML page load. You'll need to return the success/error message to your AJAX call and update your HTML manually.

Comment: Yep.  That worked for me.  I added something along the lines of `$(".flash_message").html("<%= flash[:success] %>");` and everything worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenDowney Additional note: Flash messages are supposed to render on next request, so you might have issues with persistent flashes. Look at `flash.now` if that happens.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the tip. :)